# Is it true that every RelativeLayout in Android can be programmed with a LinearLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout

As far as I understand Layouts in Android I just wanted to ask whether the following statement is true or not ?

Is it true that every RelativeLayout in Android can be programmed with a LinearLayout ?

I personally believe that every RelativeLayout can be also done with a LinearLayout. So why should someone use RelativeLayout rather than a Linear ?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is it true that every RelativeLayout in Android can be programmed with a LinearLayout ?

No.

First, `RelativeLayout` supports Z-axis ordering (i.e., widgets overlapping other widgets). `LinearLayout` does not.

Second, only a subset of `RelativeLayout` structures could be replaced by a *single* `LinearLayout`. It is conceivable that you could implement all non-overlapping `RelativeLayout` structures using *many* `LinearLayout` and `Space` widgets. The result may be substantially more complex, more memory-intensive, and possibly more CPU-intensive.

Answer (score 0):

According with android reference guide:

> LinearLayout: A layout that organizes its children into a single horizontal or vertical row. It creates a scrollbar if the length of the window exceeds the length of the screen.
>
> RelativeLayout: Enables you to specify the location of child objects relative to each other (child A to the left of child B) or to the parent (aligned to the top of the parent).

For more information: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#CommonLayouts

Answer (score 0):

Even if that statement was true, `RelativeLayout` is simply a better tool for certain use cases - so why don't use it? You might be able to recreate a layout using a `LinearLayout`, but the result will most likely be inefficient in terms of number of views and rendering times. Additionally, sometimes using `RelativeLayout` leads to a more simple and intuitive layout description, which means easier maintainability.